# Why is error 1452 appearing when executing these tables?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key, mysql-error-1452

I want to insert some data into some tables. However, upon reaching `statistics_per_year`, mysql shoots out error code 1452 and I do not know why this is.

error:

```
17:54:58    INSERT INTO statistics_per_year(disease_continent_id,infected_id,dead_id) VALUES(2,3,4) Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`practice`.`statistics_per_year`, CONSTRAINT `statistics_per_year_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`infected_id`) REFERENCES `statistics_reference` (`infected_id`))    0.484 sec
```

code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE df(
    disease_continent_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
);
CREATE TABLE statistics_reference(
    infected_id INT NOT NULL,
    dead_id INT NOT NULL,
    per_100000_population VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(infected_id)
);
CREATE TABLE statistics_per_year(
    disease_continent_id INT NOT NULL,
    infected_id INT NOT NULL,
    dead_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(infected_id) REFERENCES statistics_reference(infected_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(disease_continent_id) REFERENCES df(disease_continent_id)
);
INSERT INTO df(disease_continent_id)
VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO statistics_reference(infected_id,dead_id,per_100000_population)
VALUES(1,2,"fff");
INSERT INTO statistics_per_year(disease_continent_id,infected_id,dead_id)
VALUES(1,3,4);
```

Comment: Because you're trying to add a row into `statistics_per_year` with a value of `3` for `infected_id`, which does not exist in the `statistics_reference` table. The error message very clearly explains what the problem is, and specifically tells you what the constraint is that's being violated if you read the error message.

Comment: I've noticed that this question has been dubbed as a 'duplicate' on Stackoverflow. Does that mean I am suppose to remove this question?

Answer (score 0):

Your schema stays:

```
CREATE TABLE statistics_per_year(
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY(infected_id) REFERENCES statistics_reference(infected_id),
    ...
);
```

This means: every value that you insert in `statistics_per_year(infected_id)` must exist in `statistics_reference(infected_id)`.

---

You do:

```
INSERT INTO statistics_reference
    (infected_id,dead_id,per_100000_population) 
    VALUES(1,2,"fff");
INSERT INTO statistics_per_year
    (disease_continent_id,infected_id,dead_id) 
    VALUES(1,3,4);
```

Table `statistics_reference` contains just one record, with `infected_id = 1`. You are trying to insert a record in dependant table `statistics_per_year` with `infected_id = 3`. This fails because there is no parent record for that value in `statistics_reference`.

You can either insert the missing parent record in `statistics_reference`, or change the `insert` in the child table to reference an existing parent id.